# How to Merge Two Two Items in Dictionary Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to put two items of the dictionary into one entity in respective keys if idx=... is similar in keys then all the comparable data with matching keys becomes one item in dict with 0, 1, ... keys see below demo data to understand, I [learned this](https://favtutor.com/blogs/merge-dictionaries-python) page but I'm not able to do it if you know how to do it, please help me

##### Demo Data:

```py
{
    "system": {
        "camera[idx=0]": {
            "fps": {
                "value": 24,
                "xpath": "/system/camera[idx=0]/fps",
                "index": 3,
                "string": "fps",
                "uniqueID": "f8f90bde-e530-4cc6-b350-3e923d6ab456",
                "editable": True,
                "parent": "system",
                "subParents": ["system", "camera[idx=0]"],
            },
        },
        "motion_detection[idx=0]": {
            "threshold_type": {
                "value": 0,
                "xpath": "/system/camera[idx=1]/ip/motion_detection[idx=0]/threshold_type",
                "index": 5,
                "string": "threshold_type",
                "uniqueID": "5532aebe-501d-4275-ac4d-d6c8baf34d45",
                "editable": True,
                "parent": "system",
                "subParents": [
                    "system",
                    "camera[idx=1]",
                    "ip",
                    "motion_detection[idx=0]",
                ],
            },
        },
        "camera[idx=1]": {
            "vendor_name": {
                "value": "Raspberry",
                "xpath": "/system/camera[idx=1]/vendor_name",
                "index": 3,
                "string": "vendor_name",
                "uniqueID": "6ea8386b-fd11-44c4-88e8-b35b8eff9f43",
                "editable": True,
                "parent": "system",
                "subParents": ["system", "camera[idx=1]"],
            }
        },
        "motion_detection[idx=1]": {
            "threshold_min": {
                "value": 0,
                "xpath": "/system/camera[idx=1]/ip/motion_detection[idx=1]/threshold_min",
                "index": 5,
                "string": "threshold_min",
                "uniqueID": "c8eab5a0-e00a-44e9-8320-09e4c8243505",
                "editable": True,
                "parent": "system",
                "subParents": [
                    "system",
                    "camera[idx=1]",
                    "ip",
                    "motion_detection[idx=1]",
                ],
            },
        },
    }
}
```

##### expecting data

```py
{
    "system": {
        "0": {
            "camera": {
                "fps": {
                    "value": 24,
                    "xpath": "/system/camera[idx=0]/fps",
                    "index": 3,
                    "string": "fps",
                    "uniqueID": "f8f90bde-e530-4cc6-b350-3e923d6ab456",
                    "editable": True,
                    "parent": "system",
                    "subParents": ["system", "camera[idx=0]"],
                },
            },
            "motion_detection": {
                "threshold_type": {
                    "value": 0,
                    "xpath": "/system/camera[idx=1]/ip/motion_detection[idx=0]/threshold_type",
                    "index": 5,
                    "string": "threshold_type",
                    "uniqueID": "5532aebe-501d-4275-ac4d-d6c8baf34d45",
                    "editable": True,
                    "parent": "system",
                    "subParents": [
                        "system",
                        "camera[idx=1]",
                        "ip",
                        "motion_detection[idx=0]",
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "1": {
            "camera": {
                "vendor_name": {
                    "value": "Raspberry",
                    "xpath": "/system/camera[idx=1]/vendor_name",
                    "index": 3,
                    "string": "vendor_name",
                    "uniqueID": "6ea8386b-fd11-44c4-88e8-b35b8eff9f43",
                    "editable": True,
                    "parent": "system",
                    "subParents": ["system", "camera[idx=1]"]
                }
            },
            "motion_detection": {
                "threshold_min": {
                    "value": 0,
                    "xpath": "/system/camera[idx=1]/ip/motion_detection[idx=1]/threshold_min",
                    "index": 5,
                    "string": "threshold_min",
                    "uniqueID": "c8eab5a0-e00a-44e9-8320-09e4c8243505",
                    "editable": True,
                    "parent": "system",
                    "subParents": [
                        "system",
                        "camera[idx=1]",
                        "ip",
                        "motion_detection[idx=1]",
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my best attempt at solving your problem - I effectively broke the problem down into a couple steps:

1. Get the key you want to parse (e.g. the `camera[idx=0]`).
2. Extract both the leading label and the value of the idx (in the above case, `camera` and `0`).

If you solve those two points, the rest is fairly easy to figure out.

---

I solved the problem by relying on a little bit of regex. Here is my solution:

```py
import re

data = ...  # This is the input data structure you supplied in your example. Omitted for brevity.

outputs = {}

for key, value in data["system"].items():
    label, idx = re.search(r"(.+)\[idx=(.+)\]", key).groups()

    if idx not in outputs:
        outputs[idx] = {}

    outputs[idx][label] = {**value, **value}

outputs = {"system": outputs}  # Restructure according to required spec.
print(outputs)
```

This gave me the desired output. Hope that helps! :)